# Change default collation for Firebird database and tables

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a Firebird database with charset `WIN1251`. The database already has several tables. Now I want to change the default collation to `WIN1251_UA`. So I had executed this statement:

```
ALTER CHARACTER SET WIN1251 SET DEFAULT COLLATION WIN1251_UA
```

According to [this link](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-charset.html) query above changes the default collation for the database.

Now, I'm faced with a problem, for all tables all `varchar` fields still have collation `WIN1251`. How can I change default collation for all existing tables too?

I'm using Firebird 2.5.

Comment: the most reliable if not very fast way would be to create create new column in new charset, copy there content of old column, drop old column and rename new column to old name, Read http://www.sql.ru/forum/297195

Comment: @Arioch there are too many tables for this.

Comment: enumerate them and auto-create the script

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the collation of a column. You will need to create a new column and copy the data, or create a new empty database with the correct DDL and use a database pump to move the data from one to the other.

See also [this thread in Firebird-support](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2009/1/99893.html).

Comment: it's not true. Of course i can change the collation. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. For example if i want to change collation for all `txt` fields in all tables. I can do this with this query:

```
update RDB$RELATION_FIELDS set
RDB$COLLATION_ID = 2
where  rdb$view_context is null and rdb$field_name='TXT';
```

Of course query above will fail if `txt` field in some table is a part of integrity constraint.

In this manner I can change other fields which used in `sort` clause.

Comment: System table updates are hacks. This doesn't work with Firebird 3, as modification of system tables is no longer allowed, and it can break in unexpected ways in earlier versions if you have indexes on that field, check constraints, etc, or use the field in a comparison in a view or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

What about using IBExpert and its ibeblock, for creating sql dump of database. When you have it created just change collate within.

an example of such ibeblock:

```
execute ibeblock
as
begin
cbb = 'execute ibeblock (
       LogLine variant)
     as
     begin
       ibec_progress(LogLine);
     end';

DB = ibec_CreateConnection(__ctInterBase, 
                         'DBName="127.0.0.1:mydatabase";
                          ClientLib=gds32.dll;
                          User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; Names=WIN1251; SqlDialect=3');
   try
     ibec_ExtractMetadata(DB, 'c:\test\db.sql',
                         'GenerateCreate;
                          IncludePassword;
                          SetGenerators;
                          ExtractDescriptions;
                          UseComment;
                          ExtractBLOBs;
                          DateFormat=YYYY-MM-DD;
                          DateTimeFormat=YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS;
                          DataTables=MY_TABLE1,MY_TABLE2', 
                          cbb);
  finally
    ibec_CloseConnection(DB);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Tnx. But I found better solution. See my answer.

Comment: so far u on fb25 u can update system tables, but on later version, unfortunately...